# Connect Slack to Stripe

Tags: zapier

My company uses Stripe with many of our clients. We have 1 phone number that is linked to all accounts and our team is constantly asking what the 2 step code is to login to Stripe account. Is there a way to connect to Slack so we get codes there versus someone having to manually add to stripe for team member requesting code? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible by Zapier. You will have to do this via https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-post-sms-to-slack or other services such as https://www.heymarket.com/slack/